How can I detect black frames and add keyframes at the detected black frame in single FFmpeg process?
How can I detect black frames and add keyframes at the detected black frame in single FFmpeg process?
I found this command via Google; it detects black frames. I want to combine the black frame detection process with adding keyframes to the detected black frames in single command.
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "blackdetect=d=0.5:pic_th=0.98" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 output.mp4

